# Find intersection in multiple lines using python

Tags: python

I have a chart which include many lines.

The data format of point likes

```
r[0] = [8,6,4,5,7,8]....
r[1] = [9,3,4,2,0,8]....
r[2] = [5,4,4,4,5,8]....
.
.
.
```

Above points could be written a chart which has multiple lines.

For instance,

```
r0 => [ [0,8], [1,6], [2,4], [3,5], [4,7] [5,8] ]....
r1 => [ [0,9], [1,3], [2,4], [3,2], [4,0] [5,8] ]....
r2 => [ [0,5], [1,4], [2,4], [3,4], [4,5] [5,8] ]....
.
.
.
```

and after I used function `find_intersection` ,

I will get intersection where positions `x` ,

positions of above case is `2` and `5`

The 'x' of [x,y] has a regularly `+1` by each `r[n]` point

I know using [:,n] could write easily, but I don't implement by it.

I'd like to implement with **C Style** such as if-else, 2-layer-loop...

like:

```py
def find_intersection(data_2D):
  for i in range( len(data_2D) ):
    for j in range( len(data_2D[i]) ):
          #...some code...#
          #append position into positions
  return positions
```

How do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly.
Decide which function you like more:

```
import numpy as np
data = [[8, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8],
        [9, 3, 4, 2, 0, 8],
        [5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8]]

arr = np.array(data)

def get_intersection_np(arr: np.ndarray):
    means = np.mean(arr, axis=0)
    indices = np.all(means == arr, axis=0)
    return [i for i, bool_ in enumerate(indices) if bool_]


def get_intersection(arr: list):
    length_axis_one = len(arr[0])
    length_axis_zero = len(arr)
    indices = []
    for i in range(length_axis_one):
        all_equal = True
        last_value = None
        for j in range(length_axis_zero):
            value = arr[j][i]
            if last_value is not None:
                if last_value != value:
                    all_equal = False
            last_value = value
        if all_equal:
            indices.append(i)
    return indices



if __name__ == "__main__":
    indices_np = get_intersection_np(arr)
    print(indices_np)

    indices = get_intersection(data)
    print(indices)
```